# Port Royale 1: Can I also annex governor towns on behalf of a nation or just vice-governor towns?

Tags: port-royale-gold-power-and-pirates

When you reach a certain rank, governors will sometimes ask you to hunt down a defector who is now vice-governor of a hostile town and annex the very place on behalf of the respective nation. Thus, it is possible to annex towns.

But is it also possible to annex governor towns or can’t they be annexed?